# Expand my OWN implemented SET by moving Bucket addresses

Tags: c++, pointers, hash, stl, containers

First of all, I am quite new here so PLEASE forgive me if I somehow do not follow all rules regarding the Question. Just tell me and I will for sure consider it the next time!

Now my question - i have to implement my own SET without using ANY STL Containers or even smart pointers. The structure of my set looks something like this

```
 struct Bucket {
    pointer kptr{ nullptr };
    Link bptr{ nullptr };
    size_type nextFree;
    Bucket() : kptr(new key_type[(int) N]), bptr(), nextFree(0) {}
    ~Bucket() 
    { 
      delete[] kptr; 
      kptr = nullptr; 
      if (bptr) delete bptr;
    }
};

size_type nts, d, sz;
Link table{ nullptr };
```

Like any Container i need to expand my SET dynamically - so after every SPLIT, the "Table" instance-variable (which is a bucket pointer Link = Bucket*) has to grow.

```
    Bucket *newTable = new Bucket [size+1];
```

I do not want to copy EVERY value of every Bucket my table is pointing to manually because it is very time consuming and I get a Time Out when running the Unit Test with 1 Mio inserts.
SO what I acutally would want to do is something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
      if (i != (nextToSplit)) {
          &newTable[i] = &table[i];
          //copyKeys(buf[i], table[i],i==nextToSplit);
 }
```

So is a syntax like this even possible? Would i have to use a Bucket **newTable instead and if I change the adress of the newly created Bucket * array - what happens to the buckets which have been created by the new command?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Just do not resize for every insert - adopt a strategy similar to STL and for example, grow you capacity twice each time you need to resize.

Comment: *i have to implement my own SET without using ANY STL Containers* -- Does this requirement also include not looking at the existing std::set and other containers to get a few ideas and tips?

Comment: `if (bptr) delete bptr;` - just do `delete bptr;`. Doing `delete nullptr;` is harmless, but the branch has a (higher) cost. Also, setting `kptr` to `nullptr` in the destructor is completely pointless - it's not going to exist at all after the destructor is done, so its value is irrelevant.

Comment: @SergeyA unfortunately its not allowed - i would prefer moving the pointer from the old table to the new one after expanding without needing to copy every value of every bucket again into the new one - but i don´t think its possible the way i implemented it

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - i guess that would be ok, but where can i find the std::set implementation - again, sorry i am new to stuff like that - although i already googled sample implementation but did not find something which I could eventually also understand :)

Comment: @StefanPadu *i need to expand my SET dynamically* -- So you want to expand it each and every time you add a single entry?  Just that alone should indicate this is not a good idea -- you will be doing all of this moving, pointers or no pointers, just on an addition of a single entry.   -- *unfortunately its not allowed* -- why?  Creating a "capacity" that is different from "size" is the way these things are implemented.  Once "capacity" is reached, then you allocate.  This technique is well-known, so I don't understand the "not allowed" criteria.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - no i would just have to split on bucket and expand as soon as the bucket has an Overflow (one bucket has N places to save values) - son if N = 10 than at about every 10 inserts there has to be an expand - i know, its still a lot, i will try what you suggested BUT just one question - isn't it possible to Kind of use the already created Buckets+Values after the Expansion instead of needing to copy them? That would be a much better Option for me.